# How does LayerList xml interrupted in android?

Tags: java, android, xml, drawable, layer-list

In the official site [Layer List explanation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource#LayerList) there is an example that I can't understand.

The example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <bitmap
            android:gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/android_red" />
    </item>
    <item
        android:left="10dp"
        android:top="10dp">
        <bitmap
            android:gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/android_green" />
    </item>
    <item
        android:left="20dp"
        android:top="20dp">
        <bitmap
            android:gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/android_blue" />
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

The output:

[image: Output]

I can't understand two things:

1. Why the **Red** android isn't in the center. He is the only one who doesn't have *top* or *left* offset. Maybe I don't understand the meaning of top and left offset, From which point the offset is calculated?
2. Does *android: gravity="center"* is in relation to all containers or in relation to the item above ("his sibling), i.e., does the second item is in relation to the container or to the first item?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think if you copy this code and try to explore it you can get the idea.
in fact the red android is in the center but it is not clear in this picture , so if you put it in imageView it will look like this
[image]

i gave background yellow color to be clear , so you can see that the red android is in the center.

2- android: gravity="center" is for the item that contain it, notice that the item will stretch to the parent width and height so you can notice for example that the blue android is in the center of its item which its left top corner is (10,10) and its bottom right corner is the same as the parent

Comment: Does the position of each item (without android:top="20dp" android:left="20d) is the same?.. Who is the parent of the items?

Comment: the parent of the items is <layer-list>, and yes without  android:top="20dp" android:left="20d the position will be the same , but when you put it the parent(layer-list) will stretch to contain all items

Comment: Isn't the layer-list is in the size of the ImageView? I thought the layer- list takes all ImageView size

Comment: yes layer-list is in the size of image view because the imageView dimensions is wrap_content , what i wanted to say is : the space you see around red android is because of "android:top="20dp" android:left="20d"" and "android:top="10dp" android:left="10d""  , without them layer-list will be exactly in size of red android , but with them the layer-list is forced to be bigger to contain all child , and so the red android will take also the size of layer-list , and here is the work of "android: gravity="center""

Comment: It is written in the link:*All drawable items are scaled to fit the size of the containing View,by default. Thus, placing your images in a layer list at different positions might increase the size of the View and some images scale as appropriate. To avoid scaling items in the list, use a <bitmap> element inside the <item> element to specify the drawable and define the gravity to something that does not scale, such as "center". For example, the following <item> defines an item that scales to fit its container View:* Doesn't it say the if you use bit map so the bitmap won't changed their size?

Comment: i think that the important point is the gravity , not the bitmap , if you noticed in the attributes of <item> there is no gravity attribute so they say "use a <bitmap> element inside the <item> element  **to specify the drawable and define the gravity to something that does not scale, such as "center".**" so this is the important thing , specifying gravity that not scale . i don't know exactly why they mentioned bitmap , however you can use gravity inside <item> without using bitmap and get the same result , i think this attribute have been addend later to <item>.

Comment: glad to help you